# Delete data in external and partitioned table in hive

Tags: hive, azure-storage

I'm trying to delete data from external and partitioned table in hive. I can delete partitions with:

ALTER TABLE myTable DROP PARTITION(field > 'xxxx')
or
TRUNCATE TABLE myTable PARTITION(field)

But related files in Blob storage are not deleted. How do I delete those files?

In other hand, I'd like to delete data using any field as a filter (not only partition field). Can it be done in my case (in an external and partitioned table)? I've tried to achive this using:

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE myTable PARTITION(field)
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE machine = 'xxxxx'

But data in SELECT doesn't replace data in myTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in the external table will remain if you drop table or partition. Only if the table is managed, the data will be deleted automatically when the table or partition is deleted.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE myTable PARTITION(field) SELECT...
```

statement can replace data with newly loaded data for partitions existing in the returned dataset. If returned dataset is empty, the data will remain untouched.

To delete data in external table you need to delete files on the filesystem.

Comment: So, if I want to "delete" data filtering various fields, I'll have to set those fields as partitions, right?

ALTER TABLE myTable DROP PARTITION(field1 = 'xxxx', field2 = 'yyyy', field3 = 'zzzz')

Comment: @solalla To delete data in external table you need to delete files on the filesystem. If you drop partition in external table, files will remain

Comment: To delete data and files, external table can be changed to managed like this: 

ALTER TABLE myTable SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE');

Then:

ALTER TABLE myTable DROP PARTITION(field > 'xxxx') 

And finally:

ALTER TABLE myTable SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');

It worked for me.